# HANA Studio / BW Modelling Exception opening Info Object

Tags: sap-bw

I downloaded Eclipse and installed the SAP plug-ins.

When opening a InfoObject I get the following Exception:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sap.bw.editor.ui.editor.BwMultiPageEditor.addPages(BwMultiPageEditor.java:757)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.createPages(FormEditor.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.SharedHeaderFormEditor.createPages(SharedHeaderFormEditor.java:102)
    at com.sap.bw.editor.ui.editor.BwMultiPageEditor.createPages(BwMultiPageEditor.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPartControl(CompatibilityEditor.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:340)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:966)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:931)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:975)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:757)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$1.handleEvent(PartServiceImpl.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4821)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:211)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:617)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1214)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3261)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$25(WorkbenchPage.java:3176)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3158)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3117)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3107)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:563)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:518)
    at com.sap.bw.core.ui.internal.EditorService.openEditorInternal(EditorService.java:249)
    at com.sap.bw.core.ui.internal.EditorService.openEditor(EditorService.java:217)
    at com.sap.bw.core.ui.internal.EditorService.openEditor(EditorService.java:155)
    at com.sap.bw.core.ui.internal.EditorService.openEditor(EditorService.java:104)
    at com.sap.bw.core.ui.internal.EditorService.openEditorsWithoutProgressDialog(EditorService.java:296)
    at com.sap.bw.core.ui.internal.EditorService$2.run(EditorService.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:437)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:481)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager$RunnableWithStatus.run(ProgressManager.java:1242)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager$5.run(ProgressManager.java:1092)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4821)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager.runInUI(ProgressManager.java:1089)
    at com.sap.bw.core.ui.internal.EditorService.openEditors(EditorService.java:304)
    at com.sap.bw.projectexplorer.ui.actions.OpenEditorAction.run(OpenEditorAction.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.RetargetAction.run(RetargetAction.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigatorManager$2.open(CommonNavigatorManager.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:855)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:852)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1169)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.handleOpen(CommonViewer.java:451)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4418)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4236)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3824)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:693)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sap.bw.iobj.ui.editor.pages.PageGeneral.isShortTextAllowed(PageGeneral.java:176)
    at com.sap.bw.iobj.ui.editor.pages.PageGeneral.setInputDescription(PageGeneral.java:188)
    at com.sap.bw.iobj.ui.editor.pages.PageGeneral.createSectionGeneral(PageGeneral.java:134)
    at com.sap.bw.iobj.ui.editor.pages.PageGeneralCharacteristic.createSectionGeneral(PageGeneralCharacteristic.java:807)
    at com.sap.bw.iobj.ui.editor.pages.PageGeneral.createFormContent(PageGeneral.java:91)
    at com.sap.bw.iobj.ui.editor.pages.PageGeneralCharacteristic.createFormContent(PageGeneralCharacteristic.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormPage$1.run(FormPage.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormPage.createPartControl(FormPage.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.addPage(MultiPageEditorPart.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.addPage(FormEditor.java:330)
    at com.sap.bw.iobj.ui.editor.InfoObjectEditor.addPageInt(InfoObjectEditor.java:589)
    at com.sap.bw.iobj.ui.editor.InfoObjectEditor.createPageGeneral(InfoObjectEditor.java:881)
    at com.sap.bw.iobj.ui.editor.InfoObjectEditor.createPagesInt(InfoObjectEditor.java:802)
    at com.sap.bw.iobj.ui.editor.InfoObjectEditor.doAddPages(InfoObjectEditor.java:574)
    at com.sap.bw.editor.ui.editor.BwMultiPageEditor.addPages(BwMultiPageEditor.java:680)
    ... 119 more
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

**Cause**

The Exception states a Null-Pointer. No indication of the root cause.

However the reason was that HANA Studio did not install properly due to a "too long file name"

**Solution**

- Check our eclipse.ini file that all references are satisfied
- Install Eclipse directly on a volume e.g. C:\eclipse